# colorless bar button item - Swift

Tags: swift

I add a colored icon to the Navigation Bar, but when I open the application in the simulator it looks colorless. I have added your photos below. I added the photo of the icon from the image section as a bar button item.

[image: Storyboard Screen]
[image: Simulator Screen]
[image: Bar Button Item feature]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most bar button items only use the image as a mask. If you want an item with a colored image, you have to use a bar button item with a custom view. I don't believe that Interface Builder allows you to do that, but you can do it with code.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cart"))
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Answer (score -1):

In the Asset Catalogue select the image and then navigate to the attributes inspector. Set the "Render As" option to "Always Original". See screenshots below.

[image][image]